# Does the mRNA of the covid19 spike protein contain any nuclear localization signals

Tags: proteins, vaccination, mrna

Does the covid19 spike protein amino acid sequence, as used in the covid19 vaccines, contain a nuclear localization signal. Because if they do, isn't there a chance that the RNA can find its way to the cell's nucleus?

In the case of the AZ and J&J vaccines, which use adenovirus vector DNA to encode for the spike protein. Is there a chance that the DNA of the vaccine could get incorporated into the genome, as described here https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2570152/ ?

There is a further discussion of this potential problem here
https://cassandravoices.com/science-environment/science/healthy-people-do-not-require-genetic-vaccination/

Comment: And what should happen there?

Comment: Avoid degradation, change the genome? HIV does this and has sequence motif similarity with covid.

Comment: You would need a reverse transcriptase, which is not present in the nucleus.

Comment: My understanding is that all of the sequence similarity with HIV is purely coincidental nonsense, and that the similarity is no stronger than similarity with completely separate genomes. It's like wondering if the mailman is your real father because you noticed he has a nose and by golly you have a nose too.

Comment: Well, there is the LiNE-1 RT which is localised in the nucleus.

Comment: Bryan, Whether you believe in coincidences or not is neither here nor there.

Comment: I kind of expected the question would be downvoted, but is no one really interested in the answer, have we all gone political now?

Comment: @ejectamenta I don't think this is a question of politics, but the fact that your question makes it appear that you have a significant lack of understanding about the underlying biology here. Perhaps you could try to explain the context of your question in more detail, illustrating what you know about the processes that leads to to be concerned about this in the first place.

Comment: "significant lack of understanding about the underlying biology here" I really don't see the need to cast aspersions or patronise. I also don't think this is the place to present a thesis. If back ground knowledge is required there is always Wikipedia. eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_localization_sequence I also don't see that my question is particularly out of place given the other questions being asked on stack biology.

Comment: I think OP's question is valid and the reasons people are suggesting to close the question are complete bogus. OP might come off as abrasive but that is no reason to vote close. The quality of the question is okay. I tried an attempt to answer it, but I still think that the largest obstacle here is that @ejectamenta may not appreciate the difference between DNA (human genome), the viral RNA genome, the viral proteome, and the spike proteins specifically, which are just a few specific proteins. And also that integrating into the genome and localizing to it are two completely different things!

Comment: The term nuclear localization signal is not to be found in your reference. How come you refer to protein, not to DNA/RNA? 
Quote from your reference: "Some (...) requirements for targeted integration have been elucidated. The AAV components that are required have been identified. These include the ITRs (in cis), Rep78 or Rep68 (in trans), and a 138-bp sequence termed the integration efficiency element (IEE), located within the P5 promoter in cis..." 
What you refer to is "integration efficiency element" or the like, it is not "nuclear localization element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the mRNA of the covid19 spike protein contain any nuclear
> localization signals?

I take it you are talking about the coronavirus SARS-CoV-2, and asking whether its RNA genome contains any nuclear localization signals that act post-translationally as signals to specifically import the spike proteins into the nucleus. **I cannot find any reports where any of the spike proteins are nucleus-imported, i.e. the spike proteins do not have any (working) nuclear localization signal as far as we can tell.**

Some of the proteins coded within its RNA genome are however imported into the nucleus. These are not the spike proteins though.

If you are interested in where the proteins localize within the infected cell, I suggest the following article as a very excellent starting place:
[A systemic and molecular study of subcellular localization of SARS-CoV-2 proteins](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41392-020-00372-8)

As for the mRNA, I cannot find any evidence that it localizes to the nucleus. However, there have been reports that [other coronavirus' mRNA can localize to the nucleus](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7114095/), that [CoV-1 contains a nuclear export motif](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7114319/), and that [other coronavirus RNA can localize at the nuclear pore complex to interfere with trafficking between cytoplasm and nucleus space](https://www.pnas.org/content/117/45/28344) (i.e. at the gateway into the nucleus, but not inside!). This has been shown at least [once more](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30943371/). However, these are not the spike proteins, but rather proteins like *Nsp1* (non-structural protein 1) that are not categorized as spike proteins.

There has also been [an interesting pre-print](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2020.12.12.422516v1) floating around since 2020 about the possibility of SARS-CoV-2 integrating into the human genome if we were to ectopically add a reverse transcriptase (RNA -> DNA writing enzyme) to the equation. Please read it with a grain of salt, I don't know that the paper has been peer-reviewed and unfortunately I cannot comment right now on the veracity of the research. It is also an *in vitro* experiment performed under circumstances that do not exist in humans, so the conclusions do not apply to discussions on the COVID-19 pandemic; it is only a proof of concept of integration-ability of the virus, rather that a demonstration that that occurs *in vivo*.

Here comes the cognate question:

### Will we ever find the spike protein-coding sequences integrated into our genome?

A protein being inside the nucleus cannot integrate into the DNA genome though. With RNA, you would also require a reverse transcriptase to integrate it into DNA, which humans do not have. Therefore the odds of finding a spike protein-coding sequence in the genome, especially in the germline, if you are concerned with cross-generational effects, is virtually and practically zero.

EDIT:

You additionally ask in your edit whether DNA in the AZ and J&J vaccines could get incorporated into the genome (integration events). This is a known concern as it leads to carcinogenesis. You specifically ask about [adeno-associated virus vectors](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2570152/). Below I quote an excerpt from  [Ura et al. (2014) **Developments in Viral Vector-Based Vaccines**](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4494222/) from part **3.3. Adeno-Associated Virus Vectors**:

> Generally, recombinant AAV vectors are generated by deletion of the
> Rep and Cap coding regions between the ITRs. These regions are used
> for endogenous transgene expression. Owing to the deletion of these
> regions, AAV vectors cannot integrate into the host genome, and their
> DNA also persists in an episomal form. This preferable feature in the
> AAV vectors boosts their safety profile, by preventing the onset of
> tumorigenesis.

In other words, the virus is recombined and its ability to perform genome integration is taken away prior to any considerations of use as vector for the deliver of genes or immunogenic particles, such as the ones you would see in CoV-2 vaccines.

> The first clinical trial of a therapeutic retroviral vector took place
> in 1990. Subsequent clinical studies have raised serious concerns
> regarding genotoxicity, mainly due to possible viral genome
> integration. The AAV vector has the ability to express episomal genes
> without integrating itself into the host genome, and has hence been
> approved by the EMA for clinical use.

As you can see, this has been in top consideration for a couple decades now, it is of course not an issue likely to be overlooked by regulatory bodies nor researchers or vaccine-producing companies.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I just would like to comment that the LINE1 provides a RT pathway that could be used with RNA (mentioned in the pre-print) and that the AZ vaccine being based on DNA would not require RT and could just use the existing DNA replicating machinery to incorporate into the genome, that is, if it were to gain entry to the nucleus, which apparently Adenoviruses are able to do.

Comment: You are right, I later read up on LINE1, I was not aware of those mechanisms at play. I plead some ignorance on the topic. I'm hoping that a better answer crops up, as I'm not a virologist and I don't follow the newest news about CoV-2 very much. Hope the brief answer was of some use. And luckily for us, CoV-2 is no adenovirus nor retrovirus!

Comment: I am more concerned about the vaccines, covid is difficult to avoid now that it is out in the enviroment, the vaccines however are (pseudo) optional.

The following article mentions "For the latest trial, the components of the gene-editing system – encoded in the genome of a #virus — are injected directly into the eye" https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-020-00655-8 

IMO, AZ, J&J and other DNA vaccines are a risk for genome takeup. The mRNA vaccines less so, but we are playing with unknowns here. Please consider upvoting the question so that it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: I hope you can admit and reasonably plead some ignorance about some of this too, since I think you may be connecting unrelated dots. If you **want** to integrate a sequence into the genome, say with gene-therapies based on CRISPR/C9, you can use strategies originally discovered in retroviruses... But that is not what is going on in the vaccine. The vaccine comes in 2 main variants: mRNA that codes for the harmless spike protein, and the spike protein itself. Both raise an immune response. Neither can be integrated into our genomes as they are. So absolutely no need for concern.

Comment: You're quite right that was the wrong reference to give, because, as you point out, the paper itself used a different technique. But to talk again about the vaccines, the AZ is a viral vector vaccine containing its spike encoding in a chimpanzee adenoviral vector as DNA. Isn't there the possibility that this could end up in the nucleus and inadvertently perform 'gene therapy'. Here's a better reference to what I'm talking about. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2570152/

Comment: See edit in response to your edit.